# Run pip install -r requirements.txt from a specific local directory?

Tags: python, pip, package, requirements.txt

I have a requirements.txt file that contains both normal package names (to install from pypi) and paths to local tar.gz packages within the repo, e.g.

```
flask
pandas
local_dir/local_pkg.tar.gz
```

The problem is, there are two different deployment pipelines used for this repo, which both need to work.

- The first will *only* run `pip install -r requirements.txt` (I cannot modify this command or add any additional options), but it always runs it from the base repo path. So currently, this runs successfully without issue.
- The second is the problem. It runs from a different location entirely, and installs the packages via `pip install -r /path/to/repo/requirements.txt`. The trouble is, `pip install` doesn't automatically look in `/path/to/repo/` for the listed local package path (`local_dir/local_pkg.tar.gz`); it instead looks for that local package path in the location where the command is being run. It obviously can't find the local package there, and so throws an error.

With this second deployment pipeline, I *can* add additional options to `pip install`. However, I've tried out some of the [listed options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options) and cannot find anything that resolves my issue.

**tl;dir**:
How can I modify the `pip install -r /path/to/repo/requirements.txt` command, so that it looks for local packages as if it's running from `/path/to/repo/` (regardless of where the command is actually being run from)?

Comment: Can you not just change the working directory for the second pipeline step? (What kind of pipeline by the way?)

Comment: @MarkM Unfortunately I cannot change the working directory. It's docker-based, but I can't get into the details much more than that.

Comment: And [--find-links](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-find-links) doesn't work either?

Comment: @MarkM I haven't been able to get it to work for me so far, at least - but it could just be that I'm using it wrong. I've been trying variations on `--find-links /path/to/repo/`, but it just throws an `OSError: No such file or directory: local_dir/local_pkg.tar.gz`.

The only way I've gotten it to work is to just use the pkg name in the requirements.txt file (e.g. `local_pkg`), and then add `--find-links /path/to/repo/local_dir/` to the install command. However, this then breaks the first deployment method, because the requirements file no longer includes the pkg filepath.